# BillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener shows the Remote stack trace: at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerServic

Tags: java, android, android-billing

BillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener shows the below error Remote stack trace: at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerServic

```
Caused by android.os.RemoteException
Remote stack trace: at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.registerReceiverWithFeature(ActivityManagerService.java:18583) at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:2614) at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3628) at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1190) at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1159)
```

Code:

```
 billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
                int responseCode = billingResult.getResponseCode();
                String debugMessage = billingResult.getDebugMessage();
```